# JQuery - Randomise element absolute position and rotation within container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following which randomises divs in a container div.  Works fine as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4znLtate/).

```
<div id='draggables_container'>
    <div class='draggable' id='d1'></div>
    <div class='draggable' id='d2'></div>
    <div class='draggable' id='d3'></div>
    <div class='draggable' id='d4'></div>
    <div class='draggable' id='d5'></div>
</div>

function randomiseDraggables(){
var parent = $("#draggables_container");
var divs = parent.children();
while (divs.length) {
    parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
}
```

How can I change this so that the elements have random absolute positions (they are currently set to `float:left`) within the container and with random rotation and preferably not overlapping each other?

Comment: There will be those who consider this less than elegant, but you could always just give each div a different width (total 100%) and then apply a random position to the background image.  That way you're guaranteed of no collisions, full width and variable spaces between images.  You can do something similar for rotation (random degrees), but you'd need to make sure the container width was 5 times the height of an image to allow for the possibility that all images were transformed 90degrees.

Comment: The draggable elements are just that, and need to fit into their respective slots, so I don't think your suggestion will work.  I'd also like to see if this could be handled programatically...thanks for the comment though.

Comment: Maybe just check out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4znLtate/1/).  Sorry if I've misunderstood what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Interesting...probably will work.  However making them draggable your solution seems to make the draggable element disappear outside of the container when dragging...http://jsfiddle.net/kbjns5xw/

Comment: I think that was due to rotating divs that were not square.  If you re-set the width of all divs to 20% (with height = 1/5 of container width) and then just use random background position to move the images about, the rotation and dragging seems to work a bit better. Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kbjns5xw/1/)

Comment: The draggable elements need to be visible when dragging outside of the container div...

Comment: Removed `overflow:hidden` from container element.  [Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/kbjns5xw/2/).

Comment: Fantastic...please put in as solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution as discussed above:

HTML

```
<div id='draggables_container'>
    <div class='draggable' id='d1'></div>
    <div class='draggable' id='d2'></div>
    <div class='draggable' id='d3'></div>
    <div class='draggable' id='d4'></div>
    <div class='draggable' id='d5'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#draggables_container {
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    width:600px;
    border: 1px solid #6ac1cb;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.draggable {
    float:left;
    height:120px;
}
#d1 {
    width:20%;
    background-image: url(http://130.95.21.121/karyotypes/trisomy_21/images/1_a.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#d2 {
    width:20%;
    background-image: url(http://130.95.21.121/karyotypes/trisomy_21/images/1_b.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#d3 {
    width:20%;
    background-image: url(http://130.95.21.121/karyotypes/trisomy_21/images/2_a.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#d4 {
    width:20%;
    background-image: url(http://130.95.21.121/karyotypes/trisomy_21/images/2_b.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#d5 {
    width:20%;
    background-image: url(http://130.95.21.121/karyotypes/trisomy_21/images/3_a.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

jquery

```
function randomiseDraggables() {
    var parent = $("#draggables_container");
    var divs = parent.children();
    divs.each(function() {
        var rt = (Math.floor(Math.random() *359));
        var rn = (Math.floor(Math.random() *50));
        $(this).css({'transform':'rotate(' + rt + 'deg)','background-position' : '0% ' + rn + '%'});
        });
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
}

randomiseDraggables();

$(".draggable").draggable({
  stack: '#draggables_container div',
  revert: true
});
```